# angular 4 ng-select converting data

Tags: angular, select, angular-ngselect

Created an angular project using angular-cli

I am using https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select for modifying selectbox.
Getting data from rest servis.

```
that is my basic data
[
    {
        "name": "New York",
        "id": "108779345385"
    },
    {
        "name": "London",
        "id": "104207537613"
    },
    {
        "name": "Paris",
        "id": "109677701240"
    }
]
```

my.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SelectModule } from 'ng-select';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService, Method } from "../../service/apiservice.service";
import { UsermodalsComponent } from '../modals/usermodals/usermodals.component';
import { IOption } from 'ng-select';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-newaddress',
    templateUrl: './newaddress.component.html',
    providers: [ApiService]
})

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        SelectModule
    ]
})

export class NewaddressComponent implements OnInit {

    newTaskForm: FormGroup;
    cities: Array<IOption>;
    district: Array<IOption>;
    selectedCountry: string;
    noFilterThreshold: number = 6000;

    addressSelection = [];


    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    getTowns() {
        this.apiService.callService(new Method("Address/GetTowns", null, "get"))
            .subscribe(h => {
                this.cities = h.result; 
            });
    }

    onSelected(option: any) {
        var districtId = option.id;
        this.getSubCities(districtId);
    }

    getSubCities(getDistrict) {
        this.apiService.callService(new Method("Address/GetSubCities?townId='" + getDistrict + "'", null, "get"))
            .subscribe(h => {
                this.district = h.result;
            });
    }


    ngOnInit() {

        this.getTowns();

    }


}
```

html block

```
<ng-select placeholder="Select City" [options]="cities" [allowClear]="true" (selected)="onSelected($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
                        name="selectedCountry" [noFilter]="noFilterThreshold" >
                        <ng-template #optionTemplate let-option="option">
                            {{option?.name}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </ng-select>
```

here is the problem.
whenever i choose an item in selectbox , i dont see it in selectbox(a.k.a blank);

how can i pass name to label and id to value?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting selectedCountry which binds to your html with ngModel

Comment: can you be more specific about it?
i thought ngModel does not have any function here, so i delete it.Still  working and still have the problem.

Comment: https://basvandenberg.github.io/ng-select/examples/ng-model see the first example here, ngModel binds with the value of option, the list that you provided. You can either use ngModel or just set the ngModel on onSelect event. Read the first explanation of first example.

Comment: but in that example array already passing value and label. how can i match them id--> value, name-->label

Comment: interface should have these properties.'interface IOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}' .  You can use  function that casts id-> value, name->label  or you can use a different array that have desired attribute naming.